# 80s or 70s movie with aliens disguised as "men in black" that chase a group of people

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, ufos

In this movie a man has an encounter with an UFO. A couple of days later "men in black" arrive at his home. He gets in contact with a scientist, who believes in his story. The "men in black" are in fact aliens that are now chasing the man and the scientist. They flee into the scientist's house, which is built like a fortress (including electric fence).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alien_Encounters feels more like a partial match, as I think it lacks the siege scene.

Comment: @Kaydee188 - In roughly which year did you first see this film?

Comment: I guess I first saw it in the mid 90s... There definitely was this siege scene in the end.

Comment: If I remember correctly, originally "men in black" were often assumed to be aliens disguesed as humans and not actual government agents.  I think it was the movie Men in Black 1997 that popularized the idea they were humans investigating aliens.  So to me it sounds a little strange to read about "aliens impersonating men in black" which seems like "aliens impersonating aliens".

Comment: "Men in black" were **always** humans working for the government.  It used to be standard working attire for FBI agents in movies. Stodgy, conservative.  Movies about aliens would have the government guys show up to  quiet down the incident.  Later movies would "subvert the meme" by revealing one of (or more) of the government workers to be an alien.

Comment: @KD2988 - If you're the same user who posted this question, you're now using a different account, which means you can no longer edit this question, leave comments within this thread, or mark an answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is submitted. You can regain the ability to do all these things by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merging your new account with the previous one.

Comment: @JRE There's an article on the "traditional" lore of MIB [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/540919) (you can sign up for a free JSTOR account to read the whole thing), some sightings seem like sinister humans but others seem more inhuman, for example p. 151 mentions "MIB have on occasion displayed a very unusual walking motion, moving about as if their hips were swivel joints". Also see Hopkins' sighting [here](https://wearethemutants.com/2019/07/16/harbingers-of-paranoia-how-the-men-in-black-infiltrated-the-ufo-phenomenon/) (in the section 'The Real Men in Black?')

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it. The shadow men. I have been trying to remember this for years

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by providing time codes that match the details noted in the question; that would make it easier for people to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *The Shadow Men* (1997).  Eric Roberts plays the man who (with his wife and son) have a Close Encounter, but then cannot remember it (except maybe in dreams).  Here, the "Men in Black" turn out to be aliens  ...

[image: pic]
[image: pic2]

And Dean Stockwell plays the guy with a fortress for a home, largely dismissed as a kook for claiming aliens are here, but who turns out to be right after all.

---

Note: there are other movies also called **[The] Shadow Men**